# LINQ program NOT populating the database

Tags: vb.net, linq, insert

I am quite new to LINQ but some help from a field has produced the following code that works OK; but does not write the data to the SQL Server database records.

```
Public Function Error_Log_Add(ServiceDateRec As VariantType, Seq As VariantType, RosterID As VariantType, ContactID As VariantType, MessageID As VariantType)
        '
        ' Add Error Message to a Service
        '
        Error_Log_Add = False
        Dim context As RosterMaster_Rostering = Me.RosterMaster_Rostering
        Dim newErrorDataSet As RosterMaster_Rostering.ErrorLogDataTable = context.ErrorLog
        Dim newErrorLogRow As RosterMaster_Rostering.ErrorLogRow
        newErrorLogRow = newErrorDataSet.NewRow()
        newErrorLogRow.ServiceDateID = ServiceDateRec
        newErrorLogRow.Seq = Seq
        newErrorLogRow.Roster_Required = RosterID
        newErrorLogRow.PostID = ContactID
        newErrorLogRow.Error_Message = MessageID

        newErrorDataSet.Rows.Add(newErrorLogRow)
        newErrorDataSet.AcceptChanges()
        MsgBox("Inserted" + newErrorDataSet.Rows.Count.ToString())


    End Function
```

Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: `newErrorDataSet` is a very bad name to use in that context. `context` is a `DataSet` and `context.ErrorLog` is a `DataTable` but you are getting the latter and assigning it to a variable that implies that it is the former. That variable should be named `newErrorDataTable` or `newErrorTable`. It's not hard to name things sensibly and in a manner that doesn't cause obvious confusion.

Comment: VariantType? Function in vb.net have a DataType and a Return statement.

Answer (score 0):

You're so new to LINQ that you haven't even started with it apparently, because there is no LINQ at all in that code. You are using a typed DataSet, which is simply ADO.NET.

The problem is that you're not actually trying to save anything to the database. You need to call `Update` on a table adapter for that to happen, which is nowhere to be seen in that code. You seem to be under the impression that calling `AcceptChanges` will save something but it won't. The `DataRows` in your `DataTable` each track their own changes and `AcceptChanges` basically tells them to stop doing so because those changes have been saved. You haven't actually done the saving though. You need to call `Update` on the appropriate table adapter and it will save the changes and then implicitly call `AcceptChanges`.